# Clear Clipboard on Android

Tags: android, clipboard

this is my first question, so be gentle :)

I'm trying to clear the clipboard in Android.  I've read doc the doc for the ClipboardManager and the public methods don't seem germane:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/ClipboardManager.html

Any ideas of where I should start?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you considered just setting it to empty string?

Comment: I tried this... just seemed to add a blank entry to clipboard, while preserving all the other entries in the clipboard.

Comment: I believe we may be talking at cross-purposes or you know something I don't - "The clipboard" can only hold a single entry to my knowledge - If you happen to be using ClipNote or similar to monitor the keyboard, be aware that it stores a _copy_ of the clipboard every time the content changes - in which case you may need to ask how to clear the list for the specific app you're using...

Comment: What I am talking about is that in my phone (VZW Moto Droid 2), there is a clip board that I can access by long pressing in a text field in every app (that I've tried anyway) that gives me the option to paste or paste from clip board.  If I select "Paste from clipboard", I get a list of everything that's been in the clipboard previously.

Comment: Ah I see, on my android mobile, Paste just pastes the most recent clipboard entry - to my knowledge, other entries are destroyed immediately. I don't know if the multiple-clipboard is due to a later Android version than mine (my old phone still has 1.6) but I susp[ect it's more likely to be VZ's custom UI sitting on top of Android as none of the docs reference multiple clipboard entries... Perhaps someone with a newer phone can confirm. Do you see the same behaviour in the stock emulator?

Comment: I don't see the same thing on stock emulator... I'm not sure where this functionality is coming from... the clipbaord seems to persist even after a reboot on my phone.

Comment: In that case, I'm guessing it has to be the VZW UI Layer - Which makes it very unlikely you'll be able to do this programatically. It may be worth trying to speak to a dev at VZW but the odds of getting past the telephone drones to someone who can actually help you is slim.

Answer (score 1):

Try setText(null) on ClipBoardManager.

Answer (score 1):

`setText(null)` on ClipBoardManager do not Clears the ClipBoard. While pesting on some other location its prompting Paste from clipboard and this option shows all text in the clip board. As per my assumption Clipbioard keeps letest text but its keeping History of Copied text.

- Copy Text From any Edit text
- Press Home->compose new msg
- long press edit text view
- Paste from clipboard (All text comes from the past copy)

Answer (score -1):

From the clipboard manager, do one of the following:

To delete a single item:
Long-tap item, then tap "Remove Text"

To clear all clipboard history:
Press the MENU button, then tap "Clear Clipboard."

Comment: I am trying to do this programitcally.

Answer (score -1):

Android L70. Open up a blank message. Press your finger in the text input box and hold down until the blue marker appears. Select Clip-tray. The items you are trying to delete should appear in there. Press on one item and hold firmly until the red x boxes appear against each item. Then click the red x for each item you want to delete. (If you lift your finger too quickly all this will do is Paste so hold down for longer.)

Comment: But how would I do it programmatically? I think that's what OP was asking.

Answer (score -2):

Power off device. Turn device back on. Go to messaging. Long press. you will then see paste, and Clouseau. Hit clip tray then it'll show all copied entries delete. Hope this helps

Comment: He wants to do this programmatically. That's why somebody (not me) downvoted you, which they should have, since your Answer has nothing to do with the Question.