# How can I find out what's in the Android LG device "Clip Tray"?

Tags: android, clipboard

LG phones have a "Clip Tray" that contains several recent cuts.

[image]

I have found it useful in one context. And it overlaps the Android clipboard in that that if I add a `String` to the Android clipboard (via `addToClipboard`, below), that `String` also goes onto the top of the LG Clip Tray.

How to add a `String`, `s`, for example, to the Android clipboard:

```
  public void addToClipboard(String s){
    ClipboardManager
        clipboard;
        clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(ClipData.newPlainText("", (CharSequence) s));
  }
```

This also adds `s` to the LG Clip Tray.

In trying to control to a degree what goes into the Android clipboard, I check a couple of things (whether similar to previous or too short) to see if the last `String` put there (and into the LG Clip Tray) should be put into the clipboard:

```
  public void maybeAddToClipboard(String s){
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    if(   clipboard.getPrimaryClip() == null
        ||
          (   !   clipboard.getPrimaryClip().toString().contains(s)
              &&  s.length() > 3
          )
       )
       addToClipboard(s);
  }
```

Debugging shows that, regardless of the LG Clip Tray size as I see it on the screen (e.g., in the screen shot), the Android clipboard only has ONE item in it, the last put there. That is, `clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemCount()` is always 1.

Does anybody know how to access the entire LG Clip Tray? (If not, I'm also wondering how to make the Android clipboard contain more than the 1 item always reported by `getItemCount`, but I haven't researched that.)

Or do you have a suggestion about how to approach trying to find out?

Or is this Question about a far too restrictive device feature to warrant SO's time and resources?

**EDIT**

It's not so restrictive. [Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404243/clear-clipboard-on-android) a related Question that's about a device that is NOT LG--It's a Moto Droid

Comment: [Here's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4404243/clear-clipboard-on-android) a related Question that's about a device that is NOT LG.